Java | Maven| IntelliJ | Azure Cosmos | Failed to build and Run
I am trying to connect Azure Cosmos and trying to retrieve data but falling due to below issue(compile time).
=========== Start 1.POM.xml ======================
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.beginsecure</groupId>
    <artifactId>CosmosUtility</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.23</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-cosmos</artifactId>
            <version>4.58.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.32</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20240303</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>

=========== End 1.POM.xml ======================
=========== Start 2.CosmosHelper.java ====================
package com.beginsecure;
import com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential;
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ManagedIdentityCredential;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;
import com.azure.cosmos.*;
import com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClient;

import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
public class CosmosHelper {
    private CosmosAsyncClient client;
    private String databaseName;

    public CosmosHelper(String cosmosEndPoint, String managedIdentity, String dbName) {
        System.out.printf(dbName);
        DefaultAzureCredential defaultCredential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
                .managedIdentityClientId(managedIdentity)
                .build();
        this.client = new CosmosClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(cosmosEndPoint)
                .credential(defaultCredential)
                .buildAsyncClient();
        this.databaseName = dbName;
    }


}

=========== End 2.CosmosHelper.java ====================
=========== Start 3.main.java ==========================
package com.beginsecure;

// Press Shift twice to open the Search Everywhere dialog and type `show whitespaces`,
// then press Enter. You can now see whitespace characters in your code.
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Press Alt+Enter with your caret at the highlighted text to see how
        // IntelliJ IDEA suggests fixing it.
        System.out.printf("Hello and welcome!");
        CosmosHelper tst=new CosmosHelper("https://testdb.documents.azure.com:443/","<Synapse-Work-Space-Identity>","ToDoList");

        // Press Shift+F10 or click the green arrow button in the gutter to run the code.
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            // Press Shift+F9 to start debugging your code. We have set one breakpoint
            // for you, but you can always add more by pressing Ctrl+F8.
            System.out.println("i = " + i);
        }
    }
}

=========== End 3.main.java ==========================
While running above project files with IntelliJ maven and Java code getting below error
java: package com.azure.cosmos does not exist
It should run successfully with out error.

Started working after taking intellij updates and reloading modules started working.

I agree with you, all the modules supported by the particular SDK must be installed and reloaded to work with Azure Cosmos DB.

I am trying to connect Azure Cosmos and trying to retrieve data but falling due to below issue(compile time).

Below is the another approach to connect with Azure Cosmos DB and retrieve data from Cosmos DB. It uses query to retrieve the data as shown in the below output. Make sure whether the certain packages and their version are available in pom.xml.
public static void main(String[] args) {
        CosmosClientBuilder clientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(ENDPOINT)
                .key(KEY);

        CosmosClient cosmosClient = clientBuilder.buildClient();

        CosmosDatabase cosmosDatabase = cosmosClient.getDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
        CosmosContainer cosmosContainer = cosmosDatabase.getContainer(CONTAINER_NAME);

        String query = "SELECT * FROM c"; 

        CosmosQueryRequestOptions options = new CosmosQueryRequestOptions();
        options.setQueryMetricsEnabled(true);

        cosmosContainer.queryItems(query, options, CosmosItemProperties.class)
                .byPage()
                .flatMap(cosmosItemFeedResponse -> cosmosItemFeedResponse.getResults().stream())
                .forEach(cosmosItemProperties -> {
                    System.out.println(cosmosItemProperties.toJson());
                });

        cosmosClient.close();
    }

Output:
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Sai",
    "age": 10,
    "class": "7th",
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Pavan",
    "age": 15,
    "class": "10th",
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Balaji",
    "age": 13,
    "class": "8th",
}

